# libgdx Animation: Is it only possible with a 2d Array or Texture atlas?

Tags: java, libgdx

I was looking at this example https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-Animation

as well as one on Youtube.

Both feature a program where a texture is loaded (of small regions of equal size), and a 2d array is created to make them into texture regions in an efficient manner.

I'm aware of the TextureAtlas tool to aid in this process. What I want to know is that must I use these two methods?

Can I simply have a array of regular texture regions that don't require a 2D array making them?

Comment: It's up to you to use array of arrays, it's not 2D array which means first array contains arrays. For example, array[2][3] means 4th element of  3rd array. It's not a matrix or plane definition exactly, it depends how you use it, you can insert jagged arrays to an array which breaks matrix or plane definition.

Also, you can create a texture atlas or png file where all frames are located horizontally and use one array and one for loop to create animation. I name frame1, frame2, ..., frameN and loop from 1 to n to get images from a `Array`(LibGDX Array class) too.

Answer (score 0):

How would you go about making them regions in the first place? Both of these methods are a convenient way of obtaining a bunch of `TextureRegion`s.

Perhaps you dont quite know why do you use TextureRegions in the first place? When you want to draw something, you need to have an available `Texture` for it. Making it available is relatively slow process, so you want to minimize it the number of times it happens per frame. Sticking a bunch of small textures into one large one is a way to do just that. The regions are then equivalent to the small textures, or images, you used to make the large one.

TextureAtlas is more advanced method of doing the splitting for images of same size. It simply allows for regions to have different sizes.

Going back to your question, you could have 20 textures, one per frame of animations, but it would be very slow. Especially on mobile devices.

Comment: I know why texture regions are used for. I was just wondering if you HAD to set them up as 2D arrays like in the example in order to make an animation.

Comment: Im assuming you are refering to Sprite Sheet example? Only reason theres a 2D array in there is because `TextureReqgion#split` works like that. It is flattened to 1D array few lines below.